# Spyder name defined in a file and not recognized in another file

Tags: python, global-variables, spyder

With Spyder IDE 5.3.3 and Python 3.9
I create in a tab with test1.py file with 2 instruction lines :

```
a='Bob'
print(a)
```

Wen I Run this File (F5) Bob is correctly displayed on the console.
I can see also in the Variable explorer : a str 3 Bob

I then create a second tab with file test2.py with one instruction line

```
print(a)
```

> When I run the seconde file (F5), name 'a' is not defined is displayed on the console.
> The variable a is still correctly displayed as 'Bob' in the Variable explorer.

The two files are in the same directory which is the current directory for Spyder

I expected the variable a which appears in the Variable explorer of Spyder to be accessible from  different filese.
I have restarded the kernel, restarted Spyder, with no effect
The variable a is not used inside a function.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ You're expecting Python code to care about the Spyder Variable Explorer.  It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

(I haven’t worked with Spyder, so correct me if I am wrong)
When you are writing code in python, the variables are not *global* from the beginning. To make a variable work over all your files, you’ll need to learn about making a variable global, which I do not know enough to tell you about.
In test2.py, you would need to define the variable again.
It would be the same as in test1.py.

```
a = “bob”
print a
```

Conclusion: variables you make in one file do not necessarily always work in another file.

Comment: When I import the test1, it works

Comment: import test1
print(test1.a)

Comment: Great, that’s a way for that to work! I forgot about importing.

Comment: add `global` before variable it will become in global scope